# How to avoid firing Onchange event when color picker setvalue programitically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, color-picker

I want to set color picker value programmatically without firing Colorpicker On change event

NOTE : 
I'm doing some specific codes under on change event,
But I no need to execute those code block after set value from code

I have tried e.stoppropagation & e.preventdefault but ended up with no luck

```
function resetColor(){
 //Some code...
 $("#" + affectColorAreaId).colorpicker('setValue', defaultValue);
 //Some code...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method to check if it is from reset event or not and set or remove its value accordingly, I could not find anything in the documentation though. Consider the following:

```js
const defaultValue = '#000000';
$('#picker').colorpicker({}).on('changeColor', function(event) {
  if (!$(this).data('isFromReset'))
    console.log('from color change!');
  else
    $('#picker').removeData('isFromReset');
});

function reset() {
  console.log('from reset!');
  $('#picker').data('isFromReset', true).colorpicker('setValue', defaultValue);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 50px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.3/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-colorpicker/2.5.3/css/bootstrap-colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input id="picker" />
<button onclick="reset();">reset</button>
```

Comment: Works perfectly

Comment: @ThusharaHettigoda glad it helped :)